# Chocolatey and powershell: pin and unpin programs from task bar and file associations

Tags: windows, powershell, chocolatey, taskbar

I would like to pin and unpin programs from the task bar using chocolatey. I know that I can use the helper function `Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem` to pin programs.

For instance
`Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"`
I get these message

`TaskBar verb not found for System.__ComObject. It may have already been pinned
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe' has been pinned to the task bar on your desktop however thunderbird is not pinned and there is no icon on the desktop.`

I modified the source code of Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem in order to print all the operations and this is the output

```
Split-path C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
Folder System.__ComObject
Item System.__ComObject
ItemVerb
TaskBar verb not found for System.__ComObject. It may have already been pinned
'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' has been pinned to the task bar on your desktop
Split-path C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird
Folder System.__ComObject
Item System.__ComObject
ItemVerb
TaskBar verb not found for System.__ComObject.
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe' has been pinned to the task bar on your desktop`
```

Am I making a mistake on calling the function?

Moreover, I would like also to unpin programs. It seems that chocolatey does not have any function to do this. I found from this thread [How to unpin "Library" folder from Task Bar using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602424/how-to-unpin-library-folder-from-task-bar-using-powershell) this function that is the complementary of the previous pin function.

```
function Uninstall-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem {
<# .SYNOPSIS
Removes an item from the task bar linking to the provided path.
.PARAMETER TargetFilePath
The path to the application that should be launched when clicking on the task bar icon.

.EXAMPLE
Uninstall-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

This will remove the Visual Studio task bar icon.
#>
param(
  [string] $targetFilePath 
)

Write-Debug "Running 'Uninstall-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem' with targetFilePath:`'$targetFilePath`'";

if (test-path($targetFilePath)) {
  $verb = "Unpin from Taskbar"
  $path= split-path $targetFilePath 
  $shell=new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
  $folder=$shell.Namespace($path)    
  $item = $folder.Parsename((split-path $targetFilePath -leaf)) 
  $itemVerb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name.Replace("&","") -eq $verb} 
  if($itemVerb -eq $null){ 
    Write-Host "TaskBar verb not found for $item. It may have already been unpinned"
  } else { 
      $itemVerb.DoIt() 
  } 
  Write-Host "`'$targetFilePath`' has been unpinned from the task bar on your desktop"
} else {
  $errorMessage = "`'$targetFilePath`' does not exist, not able to unpin from task bar"
}
if($errorMessage){
  Write-Error $errorMessage
  throw $errorMessage
}
```

In the same way this does not work.
I know that I can use other solutions like this https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750/. However, I prefer to use all stuff from chocolatey.
Do you have any suggestions?

Edit:
On Windows 7 and 10 even some files association does not work.
The following works with windows 7 but does not work on windows 10

`Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".html" "$ProgramsPath\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`
The following works only on windows 7 and only for .ps1 file extension

`Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".txt" "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".ps1" "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`

The following works for both windows 7 and windows 10

`Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".rar" "$ProgramsPath\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"
Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".zip" "$ProgramsPath\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"
Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".7z" "$ProgramsPath\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"`

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: I tried both Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Much of this looks like it needs to go in as issues to https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues - it appears you have found a couple of bugs and have a feature for adding unpin taskbar support.

Would you mind creating all of those issues over in the project so they can be triaged and worked on? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. I will report the issues and I will hope in a fast fixing :)